# ¿Cómo hago que "sort" ordene numéricamente?

Tags: linux, bash, ordenamiento, unix, línea-de-comandos

Estoy aplicando un `sort` a un archivo CSV que tengo. Las columnas que quiero ordenar son la 8 y la 11, las cuales tienen la siguiente estructura:

```
country-year,gdp_per_capita ($)
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1987,796
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1988,769
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
Albania1989,833
```

Lo que quiero hacer es ordenar las columnas en base al PIB per cápita, para lo cual hago el siguiente comando:

```
tail -n +2 fichero.csv | cut -d "," -f8,11 | sort -t "," -k2 | uniq | head -20
```

Obteniendo el siguiente output:

```
Romania2016,10020
Turkmenistan1989,1003
Kazakhstan2010,10062
Antigua and Barbuda1998,10078
Romania2013,10080
Portugal1993,10098
New Zealand1986,10114
Mauritius2015,10125
Latvia2006,10139
Turkmenistan1991,1014
Seychelles2009,10157
Uruguay2009,10166
Greece1990,10179
Czech Republic2003,10220
Suriname2012,10227
Mexico2015,10228
Spain1988,10250
Malta1996,10254
Chile2006,10270
Turkmenistan1988,1029
```

Como se puede ver, el orden que obtengo no es correcto porque intercala miles y diezmiles. Lo mismo pasa con el resto de filas del fichero. ¿Por qué podría estar sucediendo esto? ¿Se debe a algún espacio en blanco que el comando esté teniendo en cuenta y por eso falle?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Está ordenando los números "alfabéticamente" en vez de numéricamente. En un diccionario la palabra "baam" aparece antes de "bam" y lo mismo te está pasando con por ejemplo "1003" y "103".  Añade a `sort` la opción `-n` para que ordene numéricamente.

Comment: Vaya, pues menudo fallo más tonto... Muchas gracias @abulafia!! Si quieres puedes escribir la respuesta y la acepto como válida. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que tener en cuenta que los contenidos de un fichero son texto, y que `sort` por defecto los ordenará como tal.

Del mismo modo que ordena alfabéticamente palabras y pone antes "baalita" que "bar" (porque ambas comienzan por "ba" pero la letra siguiente en "baalita" es una "a", que va antes de la "r"), lo mismo ocurre con los números cuando son tratados como meras cadenas de caracteres.

La cadena "10035" va antes que la cadena "106" por la misma razón que las dos palabras antes dadas como ejemplo.

Si le das a `sort` la opción `-n`, le pides que convierta las cadenas en números y compare los números resultantes. En ese caso ya sí tendrías que 106 va antes de 10035.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Muy buena explicación!!!